# Reading input file with names and scores, use ArrayLists to compute values

Tags: java, arraylist

I haven input file in the following format:
Rory Williams
88
92
78
-1
James Barnes
87
76
91
54
66
-1
and so on....

I want to read the scores from each person until I hit -1 and store the scores in an ArrayList. I understand how to get the scores into an ArrayList for one person, but I don't understand how to group the scores by person or to read scores in for the next person.

For an individual, my method looks like this:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> readNextSeries(Scanner in) {
        ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int x=0;
        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {   
            if (scores.get(x)!=-1)
            {
            scores.add(in.nextInt());
            x++;
            }
        }
        return scores;
    }
```

We have to be able to somehow store the scores for different people because then we have to compute the mean, median, maximum, and minimum score for each person and then the highest average score and lowest average score out of the group of people. My only other thought was that maybe I could create a separate ArrayList for each person using their name as the ArrayList name - I'm not sure that's correct though.

Comment: Best approach would be to create a POJO which could maintain the name and score information for each person and add that to the list.  You could use a `Map`, keyed to the persons name which contained a `List` of scores, but this gets a little more messy...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `HashMap`. This is a perfect usecase for this data structure. To be able to group things and access them based on it's association. In some languages it is called an `associative array` or a `dictionary`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 0):

Your method should look like this for one individual

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> readNextSeries(Scanner in)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (in.hasNextLine())
    {
        int score = in.nextInt();
        if (score !=-1)
        {
            scores.add(score);
        }
        else
        {
            return scores;
        }
    }
    return scores;
}
```

Because `scores` is at first an empty ArrayList and `scores.get(x)` with `x = 0` will throw a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

For all the file :

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> allScores = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
while (in.hasNextLine())
{
     String name =...; // get the name with scanner
     allScores.put(name, readNextSeries(in);
}
```

Comment: Thanks all - I'll have to look into that HashMap. We haven't learned that yet in my classes but it sounds like a good method to use. Thanks!